# How to calculate the overlap significance between two gene list in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance

This was my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69143816/overlapping-two-gene-sets-finding-their-overlap-significance-and-plotting-them) suggested me to ask here.

I have two gene sets from coming from expression and accessible region. So I have to compare the degree of overlap between these two sets.

```
RNA_seq_cds <- read.csv("~/Downloads/RNA_seq_gene_set.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
head(RNA_seq_cds)
ATAC_seq <- read.csv("~/Downloads/ATAC_seq_gene_set.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
head(ATAC_seq)
RNA_seq <- RNA_seq_cds
ATAC_seq <- ATAC_seq
```

My  [data files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tISk5kfAJaH5b-VCjeRUVaVCIwwgA_zK?usp=sharing) for the two sets.

I read in this [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14336/figures/7) **" P values calculated using a hypergeometric probability test."**

How can I do the same in R.Suggestion or help would be really appreciated

My original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69143816/overlapping-two-gene-sets-finding-their-overlap-significance-and-plotting-them) where i was suggested to ask my question here how to perform the test.

Comment: Do you have a hypothesis about how much overlap you expect there to be (i.e. do you have a null hypothesis)

Comment: I dont know exactly quantitatively but the study is Im trying to see if both expression and accessibility overlap in terms of overlap I am expecting there should be some overlap(sorry for the lame explanation as a biologist I lack the vocabulary to explain you) Hope you can get my problem and the the thing Im trying to replicate from that paper

Comment: @DemetriPananos I do see you are biostat person I hope you understand my problem here and of course the maths behind you can explain which im unable to put in words

Comment: The point of testing the amount of overlap is to be able to say "We expected there to be this much overlap under our present understanding of the phenomena, but the amount we saw was much greater/less than sampling variability could reasonably allow for".  Can you edit your post to include additional relevant information (such as the analysis you intend to replicate)

Comment: can i include the question i posted where I was suggested to post here..is that allowed?

Comment: i added the original post as link to avoid duplication of the question at two different places